# Como paso parámetros a un botón que esta en una fila de un datatable

Tags: datatable

despues de obtener respuesta de una llamada ajax hago lo siguiente:

```
resp.success(function (data) {


        json = JSON.parse(data.d);

        if (json.Table != 0) {

            $('#tablaReportes').DataTable({

                "destroy": true,
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "pageLength": 1,

                //----------------------------------------------------

                data: json.Table,

                columns: [
                        {'data': 'C019fechaRegistro'},
                        {'data': 'C019alertaIn'},
                        {'data': 'C019accionIn'},
                        {'data': 'C019NomUsuario'},
                        {'defaultContent': "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='grafica()'> <span class='fa fa-line-chart'></span></button>&nbsp"
                            + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='verObservacion()'> <span class='fa fa-comments-o'></span></button>"
                        }
                        //{
                        ////    'render': function () {

                        ////    return '<button type="button" onclick="grafica()" id="ButtonEditar" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="fa fa-line-chart"></span></button>&nbsp' +
                        ////        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verObservacion()"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></button>';
                        //    //}
                        //}

                    ],

            });
        });
```

necesito pasar parámetros a los eventos onclick de los botones cuando pinto el datatable, pero no se de que forma hacerlo, me pueden ayudar por favor!
los parámetros que necesito enviar son los que tengo en un json.

como estos `C019codDetalle`

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un fragmento de código donde hace lo que quieres hacer.

```
    '<a class="btn bgm-red" onclick="action_submit(\'delete\', ' + json.id_page + ')"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a>'
```

Como ves los pongo en ' ' los valores que deseo pasar.

```
onclick="action_submit(\'delete\', ' + json.id_page + ')"
```

donde action_submi es el nombre del metodo a invocar, luego con \ especifico que voy a colocar un valor con caracter especial separo el valor por comas y luego otra vez en ' ' agrego el valor que deseo pasar.

De forma general funciona así.

```
onclick="nombre_metodo(' + valor_pasar + ')"
```

Comment: Y en la parte que dice \'delete\' en mi caso que debo poner, puedes explicarme un poco esa parte, te lo agradecería mucho soy demasiado novato en el desarrollo web ! @Maximiliano

Comment: Nada, ese ejemplo que te puse, es un metodo que recibe dos parametros, puedes pasar más o menos dependiendo las necesidades.   En tu caso solo seria esto.
onclick="action_submit(' + json.id_page + ')"

Comment: Cabe mencionar que debes colocar el nombre del metodo al que quieres hacer referencia.

Comment: gracias @Maximiliano , pero no obtengo resultados de esta manera, gracias por tu ayuda !

Comment: Verifica que en vez de json.id_page este apuntado a donde este el valor que desea pasar.

Comment: claro, tengo en cuenta eso, pero igual no obtengo resultados ! @Maximiliano !

Comment: Vale, ya intentaste imprimirlo por consola? para ver si el valor si está llegando
console.log(tu_variable)

Comment: @LuisMiguelViana actualiza la pregunta con lo nuevo que has intentado y no está funcionando.

Comment: si, lo he intentado pero siempre imprime undefined, me parece raro porque los demas valores si los pinta en el datatable, no he avanzado nada porque no logro resolver esa situación !

Comment: Entonces ese es otro problema, por que como te dije debe funcionar. Estas imprimiendo dentro del método o por fuera. Y no se te olvide actualizar tú progreso en la pregunta.